# Creating NSArray from NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, nsarray

At the moment I'm creating an array as per below:

```
NSArray *data = @[@[@20, @40, @20, @60, @40, @140, @80],];
```

However I'd like to be able to create the same array from data already in an `NSMutableArray`.
I've tried this but the library I'm passing the array to does not like it.

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.altData];
```

("altData" is an `NSMutableArray`)
Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to use `arrayWithArray` or `copy`.  But of course, as indicated below, your problem is that you're somehow substituting an NSString for your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NSMutbaleArray is a subclass of an NSArray. So you can just do `NSArray *immutable = [myMutableArray copy]` or if you know that you're not going to change the mutable array after a point then you can do `NSArray *immutable = mutableArray;` maybe followed by `mutableArray = nil`. Your solution is also fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same result from your solution that I'm getting from my attempt: -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10af61bb0
2014-05-25 20:57:13.940 App[98517:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10af61bb0'

Comment: @user1542125 your problem is totally unrelated to the question you asked. and I hope you can read the error message and understand it

Comment: you are trying to treat an NSString as an NSArray for some reason @user1542125

Comment: @BryanChen: yes, I'm sure you're right. However, my thinking was that if A works (creating the array manually) and B doesn't (getting the data from another array) then I'm obviously causing an issue in the way I'm creating the array...that was my logic at least.

Comment: The second option won't work. In memory, the array has still its `isa` pointing to `[NSMutableArray class]`. So casting again to a `NSMutableArray` and modify the instance will change the content of the supposedly immutable `NSArray`.

Comment: Ever tried that with the result of subviews on NSView? It works very nicely because that is also really an NSMutableArray. A NSMutableArray is an NSArray, and being given a pointer to an NSArray rather than an NSMutableArray should be enough to let you know that you shouldn't mutate it, there's no advantage to actually making it immutable whereas there is potentially a memory advantage in not calling copy.